# How to make sense of PHP WSDL

Tags: c#, php, wsdl

A client (company, not application) has provided a URL to a php-based web service.  When I try to work from its url with SOAPUI, WCFTestClient or SvcUtil, all give various levels of non-success.

It looks very much as though there is a case-sensitivity issue.  SvcUtil indicates, for example:

> Error: There was an error verifying some XML Schemas generated during
>   export:  Type 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:**datetime**' is not
>   declared.

Note the case of what I believe should be DateTime.

Is there a way (tool?) that can help generate the C# client side/translate from case-insensitive WSDL?

Note, my web service experience is modest and the customer's is even less so sorry for the basic question.  Thanks!